# Find ip of certain windows phone device in your local network

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8, network-programming, ip

I'm trying to build C# app (desktop,windows, it doesn't really matter for now), with which I would like to connect to my windows phone, using sockets, to transfer some data... I know how this can be achieved,.

When connecting through sockets I don't want to manually enter windows phone device's IP address. So I want to know if it is possible to send some HTTP request from Windows phone app with some message, and fetch that message on computer, to be sure which IP is windows phone's IP?

In other words how to know which IP address belongs to Windows phone's IP address from Bunch of Ip addresses of devices on network?

Answer (score 0):

Fallow this Link from [Here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_get_the_device_IP_addresses_on_Windows_Phone)

Add NameSpace :

**using Windows.Networking;**

```
 public static string FindIPAddress()
        {
            List<string> ipAddresses = new List<string>();
            var hostnames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
            foreach (var hn in hostnames)
            {
                //IanaInterfaceType == 71 => Wifi
                //IanaInterfaceType == 6 => Ethernet (Emulator)
                if (hn.IPInformation != null && 
                    (hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 71 
                    || hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 6))
                {
                    string ipAddress = hn.DisplayName;
                    ipAddresses.Add(ipAddress);
                }
            }

            if (ipAddresses.Count < 1)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else if (ipAddresses.Count == 1)
            {
                return ipAddresses[0];
            }
            else
            {
                //if multiple suitable address were found use the last one
                //(regularly the external interface of an emulated device)
                return ipAddresses[ipAddresses.Count - 1];
            }
        }
```

**Edit:**

If I am wrong You want to get particular Windows Phone IP address from bunch of IP addresses. AFAIK you can't get like this. But I suggest you to Append some string when getting IP of Windows Phone like below which will vary from other Ip addresses by looking it self.

```
    string IPadd = FindIPAddress();    
    string WPIPadd = IPadd + " - Windows phone "
    MessageDialog.show(WPIPadd);
```

If you find any thing new apart from this Let us know. Thanks

Comment: this will tell me ip of windows phone device, if i run code on device.. i want to run code on computer and get ip of windows phone

Comment: `I want to run code on computer and get ip of windows phone` I didn't get your Context. Can you describe more..?

Comment: one app is on computer, and looks for all devices in network.. when it gets IP of all, I want to get IP for windows phone devices out of all IP's and connect to Windows phone device using sockets..

Comment: i cant append something to IP of WP if i dont know which IP is the ip of WP!!

Comment: Ok. Now I got your point. In that case I can't help you. Sorry